# TensorFlow with R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am a beginner with TensorFlow. I have to use TensorFlow 1.8 .I am trying to replicate this code from pure R:

```
 t <- array(0, dim = 100) 
 p <- array(TRUE, dim = 100) 
 t[p] <- t[p] + 1
```

I have tried this:

```
    TF_t <- tf$Variable(t,tf$int32,name="TF_t")
    TF_p <- tf$Variable(p,tf$bool,name="TF_p")

    TF_t <- TF_t[TF_p ] + 1 

    tf$device('/gpu:0')
```

But i have got an error:

```
TF_t <- TF_t[TF_p] + 1 
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Variable 'TF_p:0' shape=(3600013,) dtype=bool_ref>
```

I need p to be a logical vector, because it's a filter to the data that i want to change.

EDIT:

> I have tried this:
>
> ```
> TF_t[[p]] + 1 #are you sure this syntax is part of TensorFlow 1.8?
> ```
>
> but it gives me error:
>
> ```
>  Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>   TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid`indices`
> ```
>
> I have tried this one:
>
> ```
> TF_timestep_number_inc <- (tf$boolean_mask(TF_t,TF_p)) + 1
> step1 <- tf$group( (tf$boolean_mask(TF_tr,TF_p))$assign(TF_timestep_number_inc))
> ```
>
> But it gives me error in the assignment:
>
> ```
> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
>   AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
> ```

Comment: Simply use p for indexing.
`TF_t <- TF_t[p] + 1`

Comment: i have got the same error

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ben373, you can use `[[]]` (not `[]`) for indexing:

```
t <- array(0, dim = 100) 
p <- array(TRUE, dim = 100) 
t[p] <- t[p] + 1

TF_t <- tf$Variable(t,tf$int32,name="TF_t")

TF_t[[p]] + 1

tf.Tensor(
[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2.], shape=(100,), dtype=float64)
```